# Comparing dates in a MySQLi WHERE subclause

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I'm a newbie. I want to generate a report to count those MySQLi records whose timestamps lie between two dates. Each record has a `timestamp` field that is automatically generated on creation by MySQLi. When I view the timestamps in phpMyAdmin they appear in the following format `2015-12-31 19:25:51`.

I have a PHP page with HTML form inputs using radio buttons to choose "Last 7 days", "Last 30 days", "since records began", etc... Based on this selection I have a Javascript that creates startdate and enddate variables as DATE objects and I use JQuery $.post to send these to another PHP page to perform the query.

I'm getting stuck writing the SQL query. I'm trying something like

```
$startdate = $_POST["startdate"];
$enddate = $_POST["enddate"];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE timestamp BETWEEN $startdate AND $enddate";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```

The code works fine if I don't have a WHERE subclause (but of course simply counts all the records which is not what I'm looking for). So I know the problem lies within the WHERE subclause. I suspect the problem is that the MySQLi timestamp format is different from the JS DATE object format of the variables that I'm posting through. If I could convert both the timestamp and the JS variables to integers (perhaps representing milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 or similar) then the comparison would work.

Comment: Have you done enclosing the `$startdate` and `$enddate` with single quotes or `#` sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your both date variables with this (**change date format**):

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST["startdate"]));
$enddate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST["enddate"]));
```

And your query should be like that (**add single quotes**):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
```

Comment: Great - that seems to work. However I would like to compare to the time as well as the date. Should I do something like `$startdate = date('Y-m-d-h-m',strtotime($_POST["startdate"]));
$enddate = date('Y-m-d-h-m',strtotime($_POST["enddate"]));` to achieve this?

Comment: @JulesGru: allright, answer has been updated with time

Comment: no in mysql datetime format is something like that: Y-m-d h:i:s

Comment: Also wondering if the `BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'` includes those dates. Ie: similar to $startdate <= timestamp <= $enddate and not $startdate < timestamp < $enddate?

Comment: @JulesGru  between startdate and enddate will return your required data... no need to use >= its same..... like..... startdate >= '$startdate' AND enddate <= '$enddate'

Comment: @JulesGru: well, if you think this answer help you or any other answer is solved your problem than mark as accepted because this will help to others, just tick left green check..

Comment: Something's not quite right. The WHERE clause seems to be working but when I add records and refresh my page the count doesn't increase. I'm wondering whether there's a timezone issue. MySQLi creates timestamps in my local timezone (GMT +7) but I'm not sure whether JS creates them in my local timezone or GMT/UTC?

Comment: @JulesGru: what are you getting in $_POST["startdate"] and $_POST["enddate"]??

Comment: I'm not sure how to discover this. Could I put an `echo "<alert startdate>"'`line in my PHP file?

Comment: I've managed to work this out and discovered that my $enddate is exactly 18 hours behind my local time. Ie: GMT - 11 hours instead of GMT + 7 hours. My $enddate is created by a `var endDate = new Date (); ` in Javascript, passed to my PHP file via the `$_POST` command, converted as you suggest by `$enddate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST["enddate"]));` before being echoed back and displayed using a `function (output) {
  $('#span').html(output).show();
 });`Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '" . $startdate . "' AND '" . $enddate . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the date variables with single quotes.

```
$startdate = $_POST["startdate"];
$enddate = $_POST["enddate"];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```